# How to set the value of a variable to null in Perl?

Tags: perl, oop, class, constructor, null

I found in some examples, the so-called constructor `new` method contains initialization for the values of properties of a class (package) like this:

```
my $self = {
    _firstName => shift,
    _lastName  => shift,
    _ssn       => shift,
};
```

I know that [shift](http://p3rl.org/shift) is a function, but does the assignment above set the properties to null?

Comment: Perl's `null` is spelled [`undef`](http://p3rl.org/undef).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shift` returns undefined value if no items are present in the `@_` array http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html

You can test this using `defined` http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html

Comment: useful for initialisation of an instance with parameters

Comment: `shift` with no array will shift `@_` inside a sub and will shift `@ARGV` when outside.  See `perldoc -f shift` for details.

Comment: `shift()` also returns `undef` when the first element of the array it is operating on happens to hold that unvalue.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way:

```
my $variable = undef;
```